# Cygwin issue - unable to remap; same address as parent

Tags: cygwin

Getting a lot of errors like what you see below when trying to start up rails... I've googled a bit and everyone seems to suggest the /.rebaseall or ./peflagsall option in ash.exe but they haven't worked for me, and yes I've restarted the machine since then. Any ideas?

```
527571817 [main] ruby 5652 C:\cygwin\usr\local\bin\ruby.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\usr\local\lib\ruby\1.9.1\i386-cygwin\etc.so to same address as parent: 0x3E0000 != 0x3F0000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
1BA982E8  6102796B  (1BA982E8, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
1BA985D8  6102796B  (6117EC60, 00008000, 00000000, 61180977)
1BA99608  61004F1B  (611A7FAC, 61248664, 003E0000, 003F0000)
End of stack trace
527582673 [unknown (0xD20)] ruby 3680 fork: child 5652 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
```

Answer (score 6):

Same worked for me too: 
http://ficial.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/cygwin-and-rails-unable-to-remap-to-same-address-as-parent-died-waiting-for-dll-loading-errno-11/

In case the URL goes down the process is:

1. In a cygwin shell:

   ```
   find /bin /lib /usr -iname '*.so' > /tmp/to_rebase.lst
   find /bin /lib /usr -iname '*.dll' >> /tmp/to_rebase.lst
   ```
2. Quit all cygwin shells and stop all cygwin processes
3. Run as Administrator C:\cygwin\bin\ash.exe

   ```
   /bin/rebaseall -T /tmp/to_rebase.lst
   ```
4. exit ash
5. restart machine (may work without)

Comment: I'd like to add that in my case, the issue occurred with rvm (a Ruby related tool) which was located in the home directory.  So you may need to add "/home" to the "find" command arguments as well.  The default rebaseall with no arguments will not include files in this location either.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

http://ficial.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/cygwin-and-rails-unable-to-remap-to-same-address-as-parent-died-waiting-for-dll-loading-errno-11/

Hope it helps!