# Flask app no longer working from cygwin when set to developer mode

Tags: python, flask, cygwin

This problem occurred immediately after attempting to run my python flask app in the background using:

`$python app.py &`

This immediately failed. Afterwards, any future attempts to run the app, which I have done before with no problem, ending up providing this error:

```
 $ python app.py
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 962-843-370
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
      2 [main] python3.6m 37104 child_info_fork::abort: unable to remap _lbfgsb.cpython-36m-x86_64-cygwin.dll to same address as parent (0x48E0000) - try running rebaseall
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 644, in <module>
    app.run_server(debug=util.DEBUG)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mkupfer/Desktop/my_documents/01_Visualizations/eurostat/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1293, in run_server
    **flask_run_options)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mkupfer/Desktop/my_documents/01_Visualizations/eurostat/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mkupfer/Desktop/my_documents/01_Visualizations/eurostat/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 812, in run_simple
    reloader_type)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mkupfer/Desktop/my_documents/01_Visualizations/eurostat/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 275, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mkupfer/Desktop/my_documents/01_Visualizations/eurostat/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 132, in restart_with_reloader
    close_fds=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1275, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The error seems to stem from running in developer mode since when I run with `app.run_server(debug=False)` (btw, `util.DEBUG` is set to `True` in my local environment), the app works fine, but then I don’t get hot reloading which is important for me.

I’ve tried rebasing cygwin as per this post https://superuser.com/a/194537/276726, but this didn’t fix anything.

I've also tried creating a special rebase file following the steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26903394/1656488), but that didn't help either.

The app works in development mode from my windows command line, so that is my temporary fix for now, but I would love to get my Cygwin setup running properly again.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like the background process could be still running and locking up resources.  Maybe try [obtaining the killall](https://superuser.com/a/1331594/179145) command and nuke any lingering python proceses with `killall python`?  Did this fault survive a system reboot?

Comment: @v25, thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out and got the response: `python: no process found`

Comment: "Did this fault survive a system reboot?" ... I'm not sure how to test for this, but this does seem to be the case. I'm not sure how cygwin works under the hood though.

Comment: A reboot would kill anything running in the bg.  If you ran killall after a reboot, then it wouldn't find any python processes. On linux `ps aux | grep python` would show anything that is running in the background.  Not sure if this exact command would work on cygwin.  Anyway, sounds like a one-off problem.  If cygwin's getting you down though [docker's you're friend](https://medium.com/@hudsonmendes/docker-have-a-ubuntu-development-machine-within-seconds-from-windows-or-mac-fd2f30a338e4)

Comment: @v25, `ps` was the first think I checked. I don't really think docker is a good fit for me, but if it comes down to it then I'll give it another try.

Comment: What's the *SciPy* version that yo'u are using?

Comment: @CristiFati 1.2.0

Comment: Your *Python* environment is a regular *VEnv* (actually I just noticed that it's the system one)? And modules (*SciPy* included) installed via *pip3* or via other method? Anything custom stuff in there? I assume your *Cygwin* is *64 bit*.

Comment: @CristiFati I created using `python -m venv venv` Modules downloaded via `pip3`. Nothing custom beyond dll's from setup exe and yes it is 64 bit.

Comment: its been awhile, but use process explorer to see what's loading at that address, and make sure it's re-baseable as well.  Probably should make sure all library dependencies that _lbfgsb.cpython-36m-x86_64-cygwin.dll loads are rebaseable as well.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are doing, but as a general advice, stay away from any Cygwin python package, except from the base one. Use pip3 for all the rest. I've also noticed that pip often fails, unless you give it: `pip install -U --force-reinstall --no-clean --no-cache-dir`. The `--noclean` will ensure you have something to look at if compilation fails, and may need to be removed for subsequent runs.

Comment: FYI. Please note that the `PIDs` shown in Cygwins `ps` also return the *Windows* `WINPID`s that you need to properly kill the process tree. The right tool for this is using *systinternals* **`PsKill64.exe`**, with `pskill64.exe -t <WINPID>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a quite common problem in the *Cygwin* world. There are many *URL*s mentioning (dealing with) it, but I'm going to list the ones that I came across:

1. [[SO]: Cygwin error: “-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300722/cygwin-error-bash-fork-retry-resource-temporarily-unavailable)
2. [[SO]: Cygwin issue - unable to remap; same address as parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282113/cygwin-issue-unable-to-remap-same-address-as-parent)
3. [[SuperUser]: Cygwin fatal error unable to remap.. What does it mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/194529/cygwin-fatal-error-unable-to-remap-what-does-it-mean)
4. [[WordPress]: Cygwin and Rails – unable to remap to same address as parent; died waiting for dll loading, errno 11](https://ficial.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/cygwin-and-rails-unable-to-remap-to-same-address-as-parent-died-waiting-for-dll-loading-errno-11/)
5. [[SO]: Cygwin error: “child_info_fork::abort: Loaded to different address:”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602608/cygwin-error-child-info-forkabort-loaded-to-different-address)

The "behind the scenes magic" is very well explained in [[Cygwin]: Problems with process creation](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/highlights.html#ov-hi-process-problems) (**emphases** are mine):

> The semantics of `fork` require that a forked child process have ***exactly*** the same address space layout as its parent. However, **Windows provides no native support for cloning address space between processes** and several features actively undermine a reliable `fork` implementation. Three issues are especially prevalent:
>
> - DLL base address collisions. Unlike *nix shared libraries, which use "position-independent code", Windows shared libraries assume a fixed base address. Whenever the hard-wired address ranges of two DLLs collide (which occurs quite often), the Windows loader must "rebase" one of them to a different address. However, it may not resolve collisions consistently, and may rebase a different dll and/or move it to a different address every time. Cygwin can usually compensate for this effect when it involves libraries opened dynamically, but collisions among statically-linked dlls (dependencies known at compile time) are resolved before `cygwin1.dll` initializes and cannot be fixed afterward. This problem can only be solved by **removing the base address conflicts which cause the problem, usually using the `rebaseall` tool**.
> - Address space layout randomization (ASLR). Starting with Vista, Windows implements ASLR, which means that thread stacks, heap, memory-mapped files, and statically-linked dlls are placed at different (random) locations in each process. This behaviour interferes with a proper `fork`, and if an unmovable object (process heap or system dll) ends up at the wrong location, **Cygwin can do nothing to compensate** (though it will retry a few times automatically).

A troubleshooter is attempted in [[Cygwin.FAQ]: **4.45.** How do I fix fork() failures?](https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures) (**emphases** still mine). With the risk of spamming the answer, I'm going to paste it here:

> Unfortunately, Windows does not use the fork/exec model of process creation found in UNIX-like OSes, so it is difficult for Cygwin to implement a reliable and correct `fork()`, which can lead to error messages such as:
>
> - **unable to remap *somedll* to same address as parent**
> - couldn't allocate heap
> - died waiting for dll loading
> - child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization
> - STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
> - **resource temporarily unavailable**
>
> Potential solutions for the above errors:
>
> - Restart whatever process is trying (and failing) to use `fork()`. Sometimes Windows sets up a process environment that is even more hostile to `fork()` than usual.
> - Ensure that you have eliminated (not just disabled) all software on the [BLODA](https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.bloda).
> - Switch from 32-bit Cygwin to 64-bit Cygwin, if your OS and CPU support that. With the bigger address space fork() is less likely to fail.
> - Try setting the environment variable CYGWIN to "detect_bloda", which enables some extra debugging, which may indicate what other software is causing the problem.
>
>   See [this mail](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-02/msg00797.html) for more information.
> - **Force a full rebase: Run *rebase-trigger* *fullrebase*, exit all Cygwin programs and run Cygwin setup**.
>
>   By default, Cygwin's setup program automatically performs an incremental rebase of newly installed files. Forcing a full rebase causes the rebase map to be cleared before doing the rebase.
>
>   **See */usr/share/doc/rebase/README* and */usr/share/doc/Cygwin/_autorebase.README* for more details**.
>
>   Please note that installing new packages or updating existing ones undoes the effects of rebase and often causes `fork()` failures to reappear.
>
> See the [process creation](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/highlights.html#ov-hi-process) section of the User's Guide for the technical reasons it is so difficult to make `fork()` work reliably.

In order to reproduce the problem, I used:

- *Cygwin **32***:

  - The chance of running into the issue is much higher
  - It's not my main *Cygwin* env
- *Python 3.6.4* + *VEnv*

  - Located at ***/home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0***

I tried reproducing you exact behavior (with *_lbfgsb*.dll*), but `pip -v install scipy` failed to build it. 
Since [[GitHub.SciPy]: Installing SciPy on Windows](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Installing_SciPy/Windows.html) describes a quite complex process, and I'd have no guarantee that at the end I'd be able to reproduce the problem, I tried with *numpy*'s *.dll*s (*numpy* was successfully installed as a *scipy* dependency), but I wasn't able to (as a side effect, `import numpy` loads a bunch of *.dll*s), but calling *fork* (**via *subprocess.Popen***) didn't fail. 
Then I decided to take matter into my own hands, and create a small program that loads some *.dll*s, then forks itself (again, via *subprocess.Popen*), to make the problem as reproducible as possible.

*dll.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL_EXPORT
#endif


DLL_EXPORT int test() {
    printf("[%s] (%d) - [%s]\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
}
```

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os
import subprocess
import time
import select
import random
import ctypes


DLLS = [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "dll{:d}.dll".format(item)) for item in range(2)]


def main():
    random.seed(os.getpid())
    random.shuffle(DLLS)
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version.replace("\n", ""), sys.platform))
        print("Process 0x{:08X}".format(os.getpid()))
        for dll in DLLS:
            ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(dll)
        idx = 0
        while sys.stdin not in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 1)[0]:
            p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable] + sys.argv + [str(idx)])
            #p.communicate()
            time.sleep(1)
            idx += 1
        
    else:
        sleep_time = 3
        print("Process 0x{:08X} (inner) will end in {:d} seconds".format(os.getpid(), sleep_time))
        time.sleep(sleep_time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- The scenario is a bit different, instead of a *Python Extension Module*, I have a regular (dummy) *.dll*, which I attempt loading it via [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes). This should make no difference, as no matter how *Python* sees it (as an module, or as an external *.dll*) **it will still have to load it** into the process (the same way)
- The scenario is:

  - I load 2 such *.dll*s (actually **it's the same *.dll*** copied under a different name, so they both have the same *Preferred Base Address*), so the 1<sup>st</sup> *.dll* will probably be loaded at that address, while the next *.dll* will be loaded at a different one
  - Then I *fork* the process, and in the child, based on a random factor, I switch the *.dll* loading order
  - When the 2<sup>nd</sup> *.dll* will be loaded at the preferred base, there'll be an inconsistency with the parent process, yielding the error
- At the beginning everything was in my *cwd*, then (to be closer to your problem), I created a *Python* package with the files. Note that I didn't do it the proper way (installation via a *setup.py* file), but manually copying everything

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q054370263]> ~/sopr.sh
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> uname -a
> CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW cfati-5510-0 2.11.2(0.329/5/3) 2018-11-08 14:30 i686 Cygwin
> [prompt]> ls
> code.py  dll.c  scipy.txt
> [prompt]> # List the currently installed packages in the !!! VEENV !!! Python
> [prompt]> ls -l ~/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> total 33
> drwxr-xr-x+ 1 cfati None   0 Jan 30 01:40 __pycache__
> -rw-r--r--  1 cfati None 126 Jan 30 01:40 easy_install.py
> drwxr-xr-x+ 1 cfati None   0 Feb  2 21:41 numpy
> drwxr-xr-x+ 1 cfati None   0 Feb  2 21:41 numpy-1.16.1.dist-info
> drwxr-xr-x+ 1 cfati None   0 Jan 30 01:40 pip
> drwxr-xr-x+ 1 cfati None   0 Jan 30 01:40 pip-19.0.1.dist-info
> drwxr-xr-x+ 1 cfati None   0 Jan 30 01:40 pkg_resources
> drwxr-xr-x+ 1 cfati None   0 Jan 30 01:40 setuptools
> drwxr-xr-x+ 1 cfati None   0 Jan 30 01:40 setuptools-40.7.1.dist-info
> drwxr-xr-x+ 1 cfati None   0 Jan 30 01:40 wheel
> drwxr-xr-x+ 1 cfati None   0 Jan 30 01:40 wheel-0.32.3.dist-info
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> ~/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/bin/python -m q054370263
> /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/bin/python: No module named q054370263
> [prompt]> # Create the package in site-packages dir
> [prompt]> mkdir ~/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263
> [prompt]> cp code.py ~/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263/__main__.py
> [prompt]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o ~/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263/dll0.dll dll.c
> [prompt]> cp ~/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263/dll0.dll ~/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263/dll1.dll
> [prompt]> ls
> code.py  dll.c  scipy.txt
> [prompt]> ls -l ~/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263
> total 260
> -rwxr-x---  1 cfati None   1012 Feb  3 12:39 __main__.py
> -rwxr-xr-x  1 cfati None 129844 Feb  3 12:22 dll0.dll
> -rwxr-xr-x  1 cfati None 129844 Feb  3 12:22 dll1.dll
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> # Attempt to reproduce the problem by simply running the package
> [prompt]> ~/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/bin/python -m q054370263
> Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  7 2018, 17:45:56) [GCC 6.4.0] on cygwin
>
> Process 0x00001B38
>      18 [main] python3 21616 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'dll0.dll' (0xD90000) is already occupied
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>     "__main__", mod_spec)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>     exec(code, run_globals)
>   File "/home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263/__main__.py", line 37, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "/home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263/__main__.py", line 25, in main
>     p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable] + sys.argv + [str(idx)])
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
>     restore_signals, start_new_session)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1275, in _execute_child
>     restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
> BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> ~/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/bin/python -m q054370263
> Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  7 2018, 17:45:56) [GCC 6.4.0] on cygwin
>
> Process 0x000055E8
> Process 0x00005764 (inner) will end in 3 seconds
>       1 [main] python3 21224 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'dll1.dll' (0x6D0000) is already occupied
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>     "__main__", mod_spec)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>     exec(code, run_globals)
>   File "/home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263/__main__.py", line 37, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "/home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263/__main__.py", line 25, in main
>     p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable] + sys.argv + [str(idx)])
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
>     restore_signals, start_new_session)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1275, in _execute_child
>     restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
> BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
> ```

So, the error is quite reproducible. I'd also like to add here the *.dll* details ([Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com)):

[image: Img0]

#### Why doesn't a regular *rebase* (*rebaseall*) solve the problem?

- *Cygwin* packages have a post install script that calls *rebase* on their *.dll*s
- *rebase* searches in *standard library paths* (*/lib*, */usr/lib*, ...). That can be adjusted, according to ***/usr/share/doc/Cygwin/_autorebase.README***:

  > Packages can make the potential locations of such dynamic objects
  > known by dropping a file (named after the package) in
  > */var/lib/rebase/dynpath.d/*.  If any dynamic objects are installed by
  > users, these locations should be advertised in */var/lib/rebase/user.d/*
  > (the file name should be identical to the user name if there are
  > multiple users on this system)

  *Python* requires such an adjustment, due to packages that may contain *.dll*s
- *pip* like packages do **not** have a post install script (that would rebase their *.dll*s)
- The *VEnv* is in the user's *home path* which is **not** in the *standard library paths* (so, even a *rebaseall* will ignore them)

Note that **all the rebased *.dll*s are stored in a *DB***: */etc/rebase.db(.${ARCH})*.

> ```bash
> [prompt]> ls /var/lib/rebase/dynpath.d/
> perl  python2  python3
> [prompt]> cat /var/lib/rebase/dynpath.d/python3
> /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> [prompt]> ls /var/lib/rebase/user.d/
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> grep -r "dll0.dll" /etc/rebase.db.i386
> [prompt]>
> ```

In order the *.dll*s to be picked up by *rebase* tools, they need to be advertised. That can be done in 2 ways:

- Specify them in one of the custom locations, so at the next full rebase they will no longer be ignored (simply add the *VEnv* dir, and others if any):

  > ```bash
  > [prompt]> echo /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0 >/var/lib/rebase/user.d/${USER}
  > [prompt]> cat /var/lib/rebase/user.d/cfati
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0
  > ```
- Manually rebase the *.dll*s

Both of them worked for me, but I'm going to exemplify on the 2<sup>nd</sup> variant only (as it's simpler). The process consists of 2 steps:

- **Create a list of all *.dll*s that need to be rebased**

  > ```bash
  > [prompt]> find /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0 -name "*.dll" -o -name "*.so">/tmp/to_rebase.txt
  > [prompt]> ls -l /tmp/to_rebase.txt
  > -rw-r--r-- 1 cfati None 1773 Feb  3 13:05 /tmp/to_rebase.txt
  > [prompt]> cat /tmp/to_rebase.txt
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_dummy.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_module_test.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_tests.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_operand_flag_tests.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_rational_tests.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_struct_ufunc_tests.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_umath_tests.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack_lite.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263/dll0.dll
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263/dll1.dll
  > ```
- **Perform the rebase**

  - **All the *Cygwin* processes must be closed (including services: e.g. *sshd*)**
  - I launched the command from *dash.exe* (started directly from *Win*, from *Cygwin* *bin* dir), **and not from *Mintty*** (notice the prompt)

  > ```bash
  > $ /bin/rebaseall -v -T /tmp/to_rebase.txt
  > ...
  > /usr/bin/cygargp-0.dll: new base = 6e7c0000, new size = 20000
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263/dll1.dll: new base = 6e7e0000, new size = 30000
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q054370263/dll0.dll: new base = 6e810000, new size = 30000
  > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.cpython-36m-i386-cygwin.dll: new base = 6e840000, new size = 280000
  > ...
  > ```

The updated *Dependency Walker* window (check its *Preferred Base*, and compare it to the one in the previous image):

[image: Img1]

And also the *rebase* *DB* "query" (now back from *Mintty*):

> ```bash
> [prompt]> grep -r "dll0.dll" /etc/rebase.db.i386
> Binary file /etc/rebase.db.i386 matches
> ```

What's more important, **running the code**:

> ```bash
> [prompt]> ~/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_032_03.06.04_test0/bin/python -m q054370263
> Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  7 2018, 17:45:56) [GCC 6.4.0] on cygwin
>
> Process 0x000052D0
> Process 0x00004634 (inner) will end in 3 seconds
> Process 0x00004864 (inner) will end in 3 seconds
> Process 0x00005CFC (inner) will end in 3 seconds
> Process 0x00005A5C (inner) will end in 3 seconds
> Process 0x00005098 (inner) will end in 3 seconds
> Process 0x00005840 (inner) will end in 3 seconds
> Process 0x000058C4 (inner) will end in 3 seconds
> Process 0x000051DC (inner) will end in 3 seconds
> Process 0x00001A5C (inner) will end in 3 seconds
> Process 0x00003D2C (inner) will end in 3 seconds
> Process 0x00000DA0 (inner) will end in 3 seconds
> ```

As seen it is able to fork itself multiple times (it only stopped because I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: This is super good information, but it would be easier to read if you could remove all those super long *prompts* in your output that you have.

Comment: @not2qubit: 1st of them is quite long, indeed. I'll see how I could split it, to make it easier to read. But I won't do it immediately. The prompts are a proof to support  whatever I'm claiming.Or do you mean they're long on the horizontal axis, and one can't see the whole "console" at once (has to keep scrolling)?

Comment: Yes, horizontally. :)

Comment: @not2qubit: Well, part of the problem are my (long) paths. Also, I consider the *prompts* useful since it's one thing to explain that everything works, and it's another thing to actually show it (has a higher impact). Also, users can see how I executed commands (arguments, and so on). In the past I didn't use to paste this kind of info, then I was requested in comments, and so I became "verbose". I wasn't happy somewhere in the last year 2nd half, when *SO* redesigned their page layout, so that the area designed for question / answer, became narrower.

Comment: I simply don't see any useful information whatsoever, in repeatedly displaying:  
`[cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q054370263]>`. It's just annoying because it forces you to scroll left and right every few lines to see what is happening.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. How I do things is: I copy / paste the output in *Notepad++*, block indent and drop it here. I'll see how can I improve that in the future. For the past posts I don't think I'll do anything.

Comment: @not2qubit: I created *shell* / *bat* scripts to temporarily shorten my prompt for content that I'm going to paste here. There are still lines that are too long to fit in the screen (the scrollbar is still there), but it's better now.

Comment: BTW. I think you should follow [the linux](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/linux.html) way to build scipy, not the old windows one, unless you're using an out-of-bounds (non-cygwin) python interpreter.