# Zsh on windows using Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, zsh

I installed zsh via cygwin, but it shows some errors when started and the prompt looks wrong.

```
jason@Febi ~
$ zsh
  2 [main] zsh 5052 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 
'newuser.dll' (0xEC0000) is already occupied
zsh-newuser-install:23: fork failed: resource temporarily unavailable
\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$
```

I searched the web but none of the solutions works for me. What's the issue here and how should I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370263/flask-app-no-longer-working-from-cygwin-when-set-to-developer-mode

Comment: https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures

Comment: @xtt : I have never seen this error, but at least a similar problem seems to be discussed [here](https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/263). Does the error also occur if you temporarily rename `.zshrc`, `.zshenv`, `.zprofile` and `.zlogin` to make sure that they are not sourced by the shell?